# Gradle + JRebel + rebel-remote.xml without JRebel IDE Plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Can you use standalone + JRebel remote?

- I have my IDE on Box A
- I have my App on Box B

I want to be able to make gradle build on Box A and automatically have B hot deploy that.

*If Possible* I'd like all this needs to work *without* The intelliJ plugin because it's broken and produces the wrong paths to lib locations in our complex gradle project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use JRebel remoting without the IDE plugin as the remote server does licensing checks during a sync transaction and classes simply copied to the remote .cache folder will be rejected otherwise.

However you can still setup a manual remoting setup. For example you can create a "virtual" workspace on BoxB where classes/jars/wars are copied after the build. In this scenario disable the remoting plugin and use standard rebel.xml-s which map to the workspace on BoxB.

When doing changes, simply copy the files from BoxA to BoxB e.g. using rsync and they will be reloaded as usual. However note that in this setup you must provide the server on BoxB with a valid license.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Synchronization with remote servers can only done via JRebel IDE plugin.

If you have any troubles with the IDE plugin or the Gradle plugin, please contact support at support@zeroturnaround.com